# Can I limit the data that the GitHub network graph shows?

Tags: github

I am using the GitHub network graph to analyze some of my repos. I would like to limit the data that the network graph shows to only the commits made inbetween two particular dates because those are the commits I'm most interested in. Being able to limit what the network graph shows would allow me to quickly open up the network graph to the commits I want to look at (instead of scrolling past newer history each time I open the page) and avoid accidentally including older commits in my analysis.

Is there any way to do what I want to in the GitHub network graph?

Something like this:

[image: first graph example]

Instead of:

[image: second graph example]